# Trying to target a list item a with CSS current class to emphasize when active

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I tried some stuff I found in past questions but unfortunately it hasn't helped. I think the reason may be it is deeply buried in CSS classes and I'm just inexperienced and not targeting it accurately, despite my attempts to use Chrome's inspect element to find exactly where it is. This is the code I have:

```
.multilanguage-widget.readmore ul.display-posts-listing li.listing-item a.current {
        font-weight: bold !important;
        }
```

and this is the page example I'm trying to do it on [here](http://lumistaging.designiscasual.com/biometrics/).
See the list of Capabilities to the right side. Please help, I've been struggling with this for quite a while now and all my attempts have been failing.

Comment: Even after I visit one of those pages, there is no "current" class applied to a link.

Comment: I'm trying to create a current class for the listing item a.title (again the list of capabilities to the left) but yes, it doesn't seem to be working, and that's my issue. I'm not sure how to create this class as I've never done it before and usually just trial and error with CSS til it works. =S

Answer (score 0):

If your pages are consistent enough, you could use something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul.display-posts-listing li').children('a').filter(function(){
      return ($(this).html() == $('h1.entry-title').html())
   }).addClass('current');
});
</script>
```

I would put this in the `header.php` just before the `</head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would this go in the CSS stylesheet or in the functions.php? This is in wordpress, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that removes the class from all active elements and adds it to the one that was clicked on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function active(e) {
      $$('.current').each(function(i) {
         i.removeClassName('current');
      });
      e.addClassName('current');
   };
</script>
```

You can then call this function from your onclick events:

```
<a class="title" href="http://lumistaging.designiscasual.com/biometrics/" onclick="active(this)">Biometric Authentication</a>
<a class="title" href="http://lumistaging.designiscasual.com/barcode/" onclick="active(this)">Barcode Authentication</a>
```

(etc...)

I haven't tested it, but your CSS should work as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm trying to understand. Would all of that just go in my functions.php file? Including the second portion? This is in wordpress, by the way.

Comment: The first part of that would go in whatever php file is being used on this page (for WordPress sub page, it would probably be "page.php", or "single.php").  Then, for the second part, you would need to put the 'onclick="active(this)"' code inside the <a> tag that's being used in the sidebar.  That might be in a php file like "sidebar.php" or "posts.php".  You may want to do a search in your site files for 'display-posts-listing' to find where that class is being used (and insert the onclick call inside the <a> tag there.